# How do I query all the issues in an upcoming sprint in jira greenhopper?

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-agile

We are moving stories into a sprint. We have not started the sprint yet so I can't query by sprint in openSprints(). How do I query the container in the planning board that will become a  sprint? Example: If you [look at the Jira documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+a+Board)  you will see the image under plan mode. I want to query the issues under "Upcoming Sprint 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upcoming sprints do not own the issues included in them (they are actually just markers in the backlog) so there's no way to use JQL to query them. We are considering changing this so that they are buckets, when we do this the sprint field will be updated for the issues so you could query them.

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: I think the buckets featured would be great and very useful. If you can post the issue number, if it is one, everyone would be able to watch it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Version" to relate issues to upcoming Sprints and filter based on that.